# Did the Early Church potentially use corrupted Septuagint or Masoretic Texts?

Tags: contradiction, septuagint, masoretic-text

For the most part the Masoretic Text (MT) aligns with the Dead Sea Scroll (DSS) from the Essene community and the Greek translation Septuagint (LXX) which was compiled from older copies of an older Hebrew text, (Not the MT or it’s older counterpart) and obviously agrees for the most part with other texts too.

Upon looking at the NT quotations of the OT there is obvious discrepancies between the Greek translated text which aligns with the LXX and the MT.

Would it stand to reason that given the early church used the Septuagint as their inspired Scriptures and given the quotes do not align with the MT, that the corruption of the text was not from an older Hebrew text that the Septuagint was translated from but the much more recent MT and it’s second century predecessor text?

Does it seem at all suspicious that the texts which differ between the Septuagint and the MT mostly revolve around Messianic texts?

I’ll give some examples. I’ll start with quotes from the book of Joel. First the English translation of the MT and then the English translation of the LXX:

Compare:

- Joel 2:28

  > *And it shall come to pass afterward, that I will pour out my Spirit on all flesh; your sons and your daughters shall prophesy, your old men shall dream dreams, and your young men shall see visions.*

  with Acts 2:17

  > *And in the last days it shall be, God declares, that I will pour out my Spirit on all flesh, and your sons and your daughters shall prophesy, and your young men shall see visions, and your old men shall dream dreams;*
- Joel 2:29

  > *Even on the male and female servants in those days I will pour out my Spirit*

  with Acts 2:18

  > *even on my male servants and female servants in those days I will pour out my Spirit, and they shall prophesy.*
- Joel 2:30

  > *And I will show wonders in the heavens and on the earth, blood and fire and columns of smoke.*

  with Acts 2:19

  > *And I will show wonders in the heavens above and signs on the earth below, blood, and fire, and vapor of smoke;*
- Joel 2:31

  > *The sun shall be turned to darkness, and the moon to blood, before the great and awesome day of the Lord comes.*

  with Acts 2:20

  > *the sun shall be turned to darkness and the moon to blood, before the day of the Lord comes, the great and magnificent day.*
- Joel 2:32

  > *And it shall come to pass that everyone who calls on the name of the Lord shall be saved.*

  with Acts 2:21

  > *And it shall come to pass that everyone who calls upon the name of the Lord shall be saved.*
- Joel 3:13

  > *Put in the sickle, for the harvest is ripe. Go in, tread, for the winepress is full. The vats overflow, for their evil is great.*

  with Mark 4:29

  > *But when the grain is ripe, at once he puts in the sickle, because the harvest has come.*

I can put up more examples. But the point is the NT is not the same as the MT but it is the same as the LXX.

Comment: No it’s about two hermeneutic tools the MT and the LXX and their veracity

Comment: I do believe textual criticism is on topic, though a couple specific examples would help narrow this down.  You also might be unaware of the role that Aramaic translations played in this period, and were considered authoritative, (Targum Jonathan, Onkelos, etc.).  I think the question would be better served to consider the three different language categories, (Aramaic, Greek, and Hebrew).  Also, Biblical Hebrew was a dead language at this time.

Comment: The NT writers almost never quoted verbatim - they often used the LXX and sometimes MT and often quoted paraphraistically.  One cannot use the the loose NT quotes as a final determinant of which text is original.

Comment: @elikakohen I’d highly welcome other texts/languages. Bottom line the question remains the same though, was the LXX or the MT corrupted.

Comment: @Dottard they couldn’t have used the MT and while it might *appear* the NT quotes were used loosely, a closer look doesn’t seem to favor this view. There are NT quotes that cannot be traced at all in the MT but can be traced in the LXX, example Heb10:5 and Psa40:6

Comment: I fully agree that is true for some.  There are others that cannot be traced to either, possibly because the "quote" is so paraphraistic.

Comment: Or quoting an extraBiblical source

Comment: There are several problems with your approach - (1) what you say is true for these few quotes but is not true for all, (2) the Bible quotes many many non-Biblical sources but they are not canonized as a result, (3) the LXX was the commonly used OT version just as (say) the NKJV is today but that does not make either version preferred over the MT.  To be balanced, you should find some quotes that follow the MT and that follow neither.

Comment: For example see Matt 27:9, 10

Comment: @Ruminator - I agree that the title was off, but we can also recommend changes to the title since the question that is being asked is fairly clear.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo - `"Bottom line the question remains the same though, was the LXX or the MT corrupted"` I think you should put something like this as the title of your question, and make it a little more clear in your post.  I suggested one possibility already.

Comment: @Dottard - Arguably, the Aramaic Targums were the standards during the second temple period, (not the LXX).

Comment: ... One wonders why no Biblical figure or writer ever considered such questions as "on-topic" or even mentionable.

Comment: @Dottard I’m not sure what I’m to make of Matthew 27:9,10 because it is a quote from Zechariah 11:12,13. Whether it was scribal error that a shorthand of Jeremiah was mistaken for Zechariah (Iriou and Zriou) or whether Jeremiah made the original (lost) statement and was paraphrased by Zechariah or whether Jeremiah was the umbrella name of a group of prophetic books, point is, its is a quote from the OT and not an unknown source. As to whether the MT’s OT version is closer to Jesus’ quote or the LXX that’s something I’m looking at in this question

Comment: @elikakohen you mean Biblical figure in the first and second century? My educated guess is that the text was not yet corrupted. The Hebrew copies were not yet tampered with to divert attention away from Jesus of Nazareth. The LXX has corroborating documents for diverse passages among other historians of that era and as mentioned, Samaritan Pentateuch, the Targums. The only one that stands alone as unique on diverse passages is the MT and that I find curiously strange and suspicious.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: *Does it seem at all suspicious that the texts which differ between the Septuagint and the MT mostly revolve around Messianic texts?* - If the New Testament quotes the Old, it's usually to justify its claims of Jesus being the Christ or Messiah; however, that does not make the quoted or referenced passage Messianic in itself, outside of its [Christian (re)interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typology_(theology)).

Comment: @elikakohen: **(1).** *I do believe textual criticism is on topic* - Maybe, but not for the entire Bible at once. **(2).** *Aramaic translations played [a role] in this period, and were considered authoritative* - Maybe, but probably not by the [Greek-speaking diaspora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_Judaism).

Comment: @Lucian obviously based on how the Christians understood the passages, in light of the fact that all the prophecies aligned with this person called Jesus of Nazareth. It also aligned with the Jewish understanding of the coming anointed one but they clearly didn’t like Jesus, enough to re-write their own sacred texts and change dates so it stopped pointing toward this Jesus they crucified and hopefully stop Jews from converting out of Judaism.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: If someone were to tell you that the English language was invented after the Second World War, because the British, who spoke only pure German up to that point, fought against the continental Germans, and did not want to recognize their ruler as the messianic figure he proclaimed to be, and corrupted their original language just to spite him and his many followers, would you take it seriously ?

Comment: @Lucian your comment is a mischaracterization of the question which leads me to believe you don’t understand the question. The rabbinic/phariseeic community did not create a whole new sacred text (alluding to your erroneous hypothetical  example the English language being invented after WWII) rather they used the existing sacred text, kept the bulk of it intact and tweaked portions that Christians used to persuade Jews that Jesus was the Messiah. Or tweaked texts that pointed to the Messiah they killed (and they rejected). (An English Language with new words and new meaning to some old words).

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: English and German are both ([West](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Germanic_languages)) [Germanic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_languages); their split happened millennia before Hitler. They represent varieties of a once unified [Proto-Germanic tongue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language); similarly, the Septuagint and the Masoretic Text, along with the Samaritan Pentateuch and the Dead Sea Scrolls, represent various renditions of a once common oral tradition, which, over the centuries, split into similar but divergent textual expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It is a debatable claim that LXX was based on a textual stream that is independent of the textual stream that MT is based on

> Many scholars consider the Kaige recension to be an attempt to conform
> the Greek translation to the Hebrew tradition that would develop into
> the Masoretic Text (and the so called proto-Masoretic Text).

*Anderson, A., & Widder, W. (2018). Textual Criticism of the Bible. (D. Mangum, Ed.) (Revised Edition, Vol. 1, p. 72).*

I also don't see any systematic evidence of adulteration of messianic passages. More likely that early Christians focused on citing these passages and when translated into English you get the double translation effect (see below).

What you are seeing is two effects

1. *Double translation creates illusion of a bad translation*:
   A translation of a translation is less faithful than just a translation, which is itself less faithful than the original. So if in the future someone would translate an english sermon into, say, Mandarin, and translate our english scripture verses into Mandarin, those translations from Hebrew to English to Mandarin would result in more corruption than a simple translation from Hebrew to Mandarin, but that does not mean that we, the english speakers, have access to a more corrupt version of the Hebrew than do the Mandarin speakers. Obviously the best situation would be to read Hebrew directly, but barring that, there is nothing wrong with reading a Greek translation of Hebrew anymore than reading an english translation of Hebrew.
2. *Paraphrasing* In many letters, texts, the verses are paraphrased, because the writers may not have had access to copies and relied on memory. It was a different world with respect to availability of text on demand than today, so we need to apply different standards for citing passages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is a resounding yes which is why, due to the "masoretic" texts being the source of the vulgate being source of the "received" texts, the Latin cult and the vast majority of protestants have so many false teachings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.